# Expected type : List<element> Actual type ; List<Float>

Tags: google-earth-engine, java, list

I'm facing an issue while extracting each pixel value of a band: [image]

And here's the code I'm using :

```
var chloaFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(chloa_4kmOnly
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : geometry, 
    crs : ModisProjection
  })
  .get('Chloa_OC3'))
  /*.map(function(chloa){''
    return ee.Feature(null, {chloa_4kmOnly : chloa_4kmOnly})
  })*/
)
```

You can see my full code here : https://code.earthengine.google.com/864ff362ae608cf76d563c0ddc36d432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there.

It helps to break it down into individual operations:

```js
chloa_4kmOnly.reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : geometry, 
    crs : ModisProjection
  })
```

The above returns an `ee.Dictionary`. In this case, the dictionary contains only one key:value pair -- a key "Chloa_OC3" where the value is a List with 13 elements (float values):

```
Chloa_OC3: List (13 elements)
0: 0.1788403076620664
1: 0.1900564311114595
2: 0.17348288340586168
3: 0.20841252514986044
4: 0.17500080456596584
5: 0.17000115269146368
6: 0.19265432841958594
7: 0.2223980568324542
8: 0.16442175676572088
9: 0.18114174886827597
10: 0.14580301518776662
11: 0.16571506010892983
12: 0.2164652970393696
```

If you then do `.get("Chloa_OC3")` then you get said list, so wrapping that into `ee.List` is a good idea:

```js
ee.List(chloa_4kmOnly.reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : geometry, 
    crs : ModisProjection
  })
  .get('Chloa_OC3'))
```

What you do next is up to you. If you just wanted the values, you are done. If you want to convert it to a feature collection, you had some code there that needs to be fixed:

```js
var chloaFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(chloa_4kmOnly
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : geometry, 
    crs : ModisProjection
  })
  .get('Chloa_OC3'))
  .map(function(chloa){    // Think of "chloa" as an element of the list. 
    return ee.Feature(null, {Chloa_OC3 : chloa})  // which you then use to populate the "Chloa_OC3" property of each feature. 
  })
)
```

you then do `.aggregate_array("Chloa_OC3")` which gets you the 13 values back as a list. If your goal was to get said list, then there was no need to turn it into a feature collection at all, as we already had the list above.

Comment: Thanks for your help !! It really help me to understand what is happening behind those code lines